# How to add required attribute with JS to radio button?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the required attribute to a radio input with javascript. I currently have `document.getElementsByClassName("LMB")[0].required = true;`, which gives me the error document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined.

Here is the html code I'm using.

```
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

Comment: please correct your code first. you are missing class attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs don't have `class="LMB"`, add it and try again:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("LMB")[0].required = true;
```

```html
<input class="LMB" type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input class="LMB" type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="yes">No</label>
```

However, if you want to use the name attribute, you could use `document.getElementsByName`:

```js
document.getElementsByName("LMB")[0].required = true;
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="yes">No</label>
```

Comment: Your second option worked. I was using getElementsByClassName instead of getElementsByName. thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :).

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to use the class attribute inside input tags

```
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" class="LMB" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" class="LMB" value="No">
<label for="yes">No</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to use when targeting the `name` attribute of the `input` elements is

```
document.getElementsByName
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

```js
document.getElementsByName("LMB")[0].required = true;
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

---

Also your second label should use `for="no"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use like below

```js
document.getElementsByName("LMB")[0].setAttribute("required","required");
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

In your exemple, your inputs don't have any class name:

```
<input class="LMB" type="radio" name="LMB" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input class="LMB" type="radio" name="LMB" id="no" value="No">
<label for="yes">No</label>
```